# update existing file in google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I can upload regular files. No problem here.
I get an error when updating existing files
I added 'uploadType' => 'multipart' and it gave an error again.

There is a "`.htaccess`" file in the directory and it says "`deny from all`" in its content.
I delete it from the ".htaccess" drive and it gives an error in another file.

An example error message:
`Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files->update( $fileId = '1ouvREdK6mJSOu_AqGyffcuwFvmvHM4Ar', $postBody = NULL, $optParams = 'deny from all', [] )`
Error in another file shows file content

second line gives error
`$content = file_get_contents($filePath); $service->files->update($existingFile->getId(), null, $content, []);`

I am using a Google Drive Service Account
and I am using the php 8.2 version library

Comment: In your situation, what is the mimeType of `$existingFile->getId()`? And, what is the value of `file_get_contents($filePath)`?

Comment: I tried as below

`$content = file_get_contents($filePath);

$service->files->update($existingFile->getId(), null, $content, [

'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',

'uploadType' => 'multipart',

]);
`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I tried as below $content = file_get_contents($filePath);  $service->files->update($existingFile->getId(), null, $content, [  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',  'uploadType' => 'multipart',  ]);`, I couldn't understand the answers to my 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

My English is very poor.

My full code is below.

Loading a directory and all its contents, even subdirectories and subfiles, works smoothly.

The problem here is:

Error while overwriting existing file, cannot overwrite existing file.

`// Folder and sub-content loading function

```
function uploadFolder($service, $parentId, $folderPath) {
    $folderName = basename($folderPath);

    // Check if folder exists
    
    $existingFolder = searchFile($service, $parentId, $folderName);

    if ($existingFolder) {
        $createdFolder = $existingFolder;
    } else {
    
        // Create folder
        
        $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $folder->setName($folderName);
        $folder->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
        $folder->setParents([$parentId]);

        $createdFolder = $service->files->create($folder);
    }

    // Upload files within folder
    
    $files = scandir($folderPath);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $filePath = $folderPath . '/' . $file;

            if (is_dir($filePath)) {
            
                // If file is a folder, load subfolder
                
                uploadFolder($service, $createdFolder->id, $filePath);
            } else {
            
                // If the file is a file, upload the file
                
                $existingFile = searchFile($service, $createdFolder->id, $file);

                if ($existingFile) {
                
                    // If the file already exists, overwrite it
                    
                    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);
                    $service->files->update($existingFile->getId(), null, $content);

                    echo "<span style='color: red'>The file was overwritten:</span> ".$filePath."<br />";
                } else {
                
                    // If file does not exist, create new file
                    
                    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
                    $fileMetadata->setName($file);
                    $fileMetadata->setParents([$createdFolder->id]);

                    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);
                    $createdFile = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, [
                        'data' => $content,
                        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
                        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                    ]);
                    echo "<span style='color: blue;'>File uploaded:</span> ".$filePath."<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Searching for files in a specific folder

function searchFile($service, $parentId, $fileName) {
    $results = $service->files->listFiles([
        'q' => "name='".$fileName."' and '".$parentId."' in parents",
    ]);

    if (count($results->getFiles()) > 0) {
        return $results->getFiles()[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ore6M.png)

Comment: Please don't use answers to place updates to your original question. Just update the original question with your updates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error of overwriting the existing file as follows.

It didn't give an error, but did it actually overwrite the file?

```php
if ($existingFile) {

    // If the file already exists, overwrite it

    $existing_File = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $service->files->update($existingFile->getId(), $existing_File, array(
    'data' => $filePath,
    'mimeType' => mime_content_type($filePath),
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    ));

    echo "<span style='color: red'>The file was overwritten:</span> ".$filePath."<br />";
} else {
```